# Which site fits questions regarding the meaning of a portion of text in any book?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I am reading the book *The Information: A History, A Theory, A Flood* by *James Gleick*. There are some instances where I fail to understand the meaning of a sentence the author writes. Mostly that's not because I do not know the meaning of the words in the sentence. It's probably due to the use of some satire/example/historical reference etc., that assumes familiarity with, say, Roman/Greek mythology, linguistic history, some widely used colloquial usage in European or other English speaking nations etc.

When I face such a situation I try to guess the context and map it to the respective website; [this query](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/47775/42914) for example. But there might be situations where I do not have any hunch as to the context and simply want to ask "*What is the author referring to in the sentence - ...?*". Sort of a question I might have asked in a study group (had I had one).

Which is the appropriate site for such queries? I was considering the following options, but not sure due to the mentioned reasons -

- [Literature](https://literature.stackexchange.com/) - It says that questions related to "*interpretations of specific passages or aspects of a work of literature*" are allowed. But would any non-fiction work qualify as "work of literature", particularly when the query is about the probable meaning of the sentence? Afterall, we never know if deciphering the meaning would require some expertise in some other field.
- [English Language and Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/) - Not sure if the above example is about any usage, so to speak.
- The final option is to put the query in a site related to the domain of the book - like [Linguistics](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/)/[Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) etc. People from that group might have all the pre-requisites to tackle the question. But the problem is that queries of this theme might not be a linguistic/computer science query, say.

**Note**: Would prefer to know of a systematic way to address this situation. That would be help not just for this particular read, but for any book I pick up down the line.

Comment: You should do real, substantial research before posting here. If you've read something about the origin of the word *alphabet* that you don't understand, research the origin of the word *alphabet*, don't just rush to post here. If after research you still don't know, then ask here and say what research you've done. Also consider that not every question is suitable for SE: this isn't your study group or your paid teacher, and you may just need to find somewhere else to ask. Questions here are supposed to be of wider use to people, something that other people may also ask.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to the site's you've already found. [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com) takes questions about

> Word choice, usage, and meaning

amongst other things [according to their help centre](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

They have tags such as [phrase-meaning](/questions/tagged/phrase-meaning) and [sentence-meaning](/questions/tagged/sentence-meaning) if you want to ask about a phrase or sentence you don't understand, where a dictionary has not been helpful. They even have a [colloquial-language](/questions/tagged/colloquial-language) tag if that's what has stumped you.

As always, check their help centre and previous questions or even ask on [their Meta](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/) if you're still unsure that your question would fit.

[English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/) does take questions on [meaning-in-context](/questions/tagged/meaning-in-context) so that may also suit if you think that a sentence has some meaning that needs some non-obvious context to understand it.

Finally, if you need some information on Roman/Greek mythology we do have a [Mythology site](https://mythology.stackexchange.com).